# Bad or invalid link in an ad

Tags: discussion, advertising

Just saw this ad on my main SO page:

[image]

It links to [msftsqlmanagedbackup.com/managed](http://www.msftsqlmanagedbackup.com/managed/)

This returns:

> The requested URL /managed/ was not found on this server.

Even the root URL does not work.

While I realize this may not be SO's fault.  Perhaps this will allow the owner of the ad to fix their URL?

You can see from the image that I flagged it, but there was not a lot to indicate that the link was bad.  I flagged it as misleading, closest I could think of.
Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: I really don't expect much from Microsoft so no surprise they send broken ads.

Comment: While its branded MS, that URL looks wonky in a way that doesnt seem to be from them.  If it is in fact MS, they could have at least chosen a better URL.

Comment: My first image posted on Meta, and I could not think of anything to circle, highlight, or redact in the obligatory hand drawn red... its a shame.

Comment: Yeah, something is off indeed. Posted answer with my findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant ads are now off. I've reached out to the client and they are aware of the issue.

Any relevant updates will appear here.

Comment: So I assume that it is not Microsoft that has purchased this ad, but a 3rd party.  Is it at all misleading that they've branded themselves as an MS service?

Answer (score 1):

You may have stumbled on a possible scam. The domain is registered to a private person on GoDaddy servers, according to [this](http://www.whois.net/whois/msftsqlmanagedbackup.com) and [this](http://domain-kb.com/www/msftsqlmanagedbackup.com).

The least Stack Exchange can do is remove the ad, assuming they thought Microsoft is the client.